# OR search with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Overview

I want to do an OR search with one that is AND search in ActiveRecord

### Detail

I want to change the table to be searched by conditional branching depending on the data stored in the record (whether the status value of the item model is accepted this time).

So, I tried conditional branching as shown below, but it ended up being an AND search.
What kind of description should I write if I want to search here by OR?

### Code

items_controller.rb

```
@items.each do |item|
  if item.status != 'accepted'
    # search for Item model
    @items = @items.where(name: search_params[:name])
  else
    # search for Master model
    @items = @items.merge(Master.where(name: search_params[:name]))
  end
end

def search_params
  params.permit(
    :name
    )
end
```

↓

Generated SQL

```
AND `items`.`name` = 'test'
AND `masters`.`name` = 'test'
```

I want this SQL

```
`items`.`name` = 'test'
OR `masters`.`name` = 'test'
```

### Environment

rails 6.0

Comment: you are iterating on the @items array, and inside that iteration, you are modifying the array that you are iterating over. Is that really what you intend?  That seems to be "terra incognita" as far as Ruby goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for "or" was added in Rails 5 you can [read more about it here](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record). The syntax works like...

```rb
@items = Item.joins(:masters) # or some way to join in the other table
@items.where(name: search_params[:name]).or(Master.where(name: search_params[:name]))
```

Comment: Might want to clarify that the "masters" table will need to be in the FROM clause. Not sure how it is working currently but usually this would require a join call of some kind.